# How can I find source code of printf in macOS?

Tags: c, macos, printf, stdio, c-standard-library

Sorry for my bad english.

I'm using macOS 12.3 in M1 Pro MacBook Pro

I want to know about source code of printf in C standard library.

I can find stdio.h file in usr/include directory.

But I can't find printf.c or stdio.c file in same directory.

And I think Apple Open Source's printf.c is too complicate, dosen't looks like a real code in macOS and dosen't helpful for me. Is that Apple Open Source printf.c code is really used in macOS?

https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-201/osfmk/kern/printf.c.auto.html

Comment: Can you link to that "Apple Open Source printf.c code"? For what it's worth, `printf` _isn't_ very simple; [here's](https://github.com/bminor/musl/blob/master/src/stdio/vfprintf.c) the musl c library's implementation.

Comment: https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-201/osfmk/kern/printf.c.auto.html
Here is the link!

Comment: Yeah, `printf` is nothing like a "simple function", it's one of the most complex one of the C library... And it's often full of dirty tricks, like `goto` usage, variadic arguments processing, and bitfield parsing...

Comment: You've linked the kernel implementation of printf, which is simpler than the Libc (C standard library) one. [Here's the Apple libc implementation of `printf`.](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1439.40.11/stdio/FreeBSD/vfprintf.c.auto.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The newest Apple Open Source [libc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) implementation of `vfprintf` (which is the generic underlying function that plain `printf` calls) can be found [here on opensource.apple.com](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1439.40.11/stdio/FreeBSD/vfprintf.c.auto.html).

It's about 1400 lines, and yes, it is complex.

Some other alternate implementations (which are complex too) are:

- [musl libc](https://github.com/bminor/musl/blob/master/src/stdio/vfprintf.c): 696 lines
- [GNU glibc](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c): 2289 lines
- [uClibc](https://github.com/kraj/uClibc/blob/master/libc/stdio/_vfprintf.c): 1928 lines

Comment: Really Helpful!